# iOS-XCode warning while validating before submitting

Tags: xcode, ios8, xcode6

I get following warning while validating archive

```
Undeclared Use of Advertising Identifier [IDFA]. 
You app contains the Advertising Identifier [IDFA] 
API but you have not indicated its usage on the Prepare for Submission 
page in iTunes Connect. Click Submit for Review to access the 
Prepare for Submission page and indicate IDFA usage.
```

Google returns only 2 pages in some asian language when I search for that text.

I do not know where is Prepare for Submission page? I searched it in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 3):

It's only a warning, you will get it validating the build or submitting it from XCode.

When you prepare the build in the new iTunesConnect, you have to select the build you want to submit for review (it will appear there a few minutes after you submit it with Xcode, even with the IDFA warning), after you click *Submit for Review* you will get the three questions with a warning saying:

> Ensure that you select the correct answer for Advertising Identifier
>   (IDFA) usage. If your app does contain the IDFA and you select No, the
>   binary will be permanently rejected and you will have to submit a
>   different binary.

Select the appropriate answers and your build should change the state to Waiting For Review.

Answer (score 1):

In iTunesConnect, click on submit for Review. Then you're asked three questions on IDFA, encryption usage and usability changes.

Comment: In new iTunes Connect when I click `Submit for Review` I get "You must choose a build." error. Build section tells that I can submit build with Xcode 5.1.1 I get that warning validating app before submitting. If I get warning then then build is not marked as validated. I am still able to submit app.

Comment: In the previous version you first had to answer the questions before you could upload your binary. Do you need the IDFA API?

Comment: Any update on this? I am having the same issue with latest version of Xcode. It doesn't ask the questions until after trying to submit the build for review, which requires the binary to be uploaded first, and the validation is failing during binary upload. Because validation fails during upload, I have a feeling it would just result in an invalid binary when trying to submit for review. The ability to reject is also buggy and hidden. An alert to remove submission only shows after logging out and back in.